# How to ask for the name of something?

Tags: word-choice, questions

[My question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39982/what-is-this-function-called) was retitled:

> What is this function called?

Originally my title was:

> How is this function called?

I still think that my version was correct; I always state such questions this way. Which one is really correct?

Comment: You've obviously been using that manifestly incorrect construction for some time. People won't normally point it out because it's fairly common among non-native speakers, and it doesn't impede understanding anyway. Unless you're actually trying to pass as a native English speaker yourself, it's not really a significant error.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's bad actually, native speakers should help nonnative ones :) people think that it is not polite to point at mistakes but I think it is really useful. I really want to become as close to native speaker as possible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it is very common mistake done by Russians (incl. me) because "How" version looks more similar to Russian version of this question.

Comment: Well if you really want to get word-perfect in English, you could post another question asking exactly what's 'unnatural' about your **I always state such questions this way** above. I can't put my finger on the exact reason, but it certainly has the stamp of 'non-native speaker' to me.

Comment: I agree with Andrey. It is always good to have one's mistake corrected, earlier the better. And on "I always state such questions this way" phrase, my take is - you state an opinion but you ask a question. I would like to be corrected, if I am wrong.

Comment: @Andrey As a native English speaker, I think it's only polite to point out the errors that non-native speakers make if either they are serious enough to make communication difficult, or if I have been specifically asked to do so by the non-native speaker, or if I do it only very occasionally in a much longer dialogue. Otherwise its insisting on changing the subject to the use of the language when the other person may be much more interested in discussing something else. It's not polite to criticize people unless its either necessary or requested.

Comment: @Mari-LouA how can it be duplicate if this question was asked 3 years prior?

Comment: The "duplicate" is the most helpful question in my opinion, it really answers why the question word "what" is preferred. Although your question is older, in four years it has only attracted little more than 600 views, whilst the newer one has attracted 10450 views. The title in the more recent question is more descriptive and broader too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What do you call...? should be answered by a noun.

> Q. What do you call your dog? A. Lucky

How do you call...? should be answered by an action.

> Q. How do you call your dog? A. By
>   whistling

Comment: I upvoted your answer *and* @Ben Hocking's, but I expect his will get more in the long run because it specifically addresses the confusion re program function calling conventions. Shame really, because yours illustrates the general case of How/What very neatly.

Comment: After reading Ben Jackon's comment on my answer, I concur with FumbleFingers.

Comment: @Ben Hocking, @rest_day: You guys should pool your answers. They're both good, but either on its own is incomplete.

Comment: I like to think, I expanded on @Ben Hocking's answer. Both are really similar, if you ask me. Also thanks to all who upvoted my answer. Feels nice when your first answer is appreciated thus.

Answer (score 20):

`How is this function called?` is a different question from `What is this function called?` The latter question is asking for a name of the function, whereas the former question is asking for the proper way to call the function, which might require specific arguments, etc.

Comment: +1. In other words, if you want to know the name of something, you must ask *What is this called?*. The other use (*how*) is only ever used in very limited contexts, and with a different meaning.

Comment: This answer is specific to the word "function" (as in computer function, not mathematical function as in the linked context) to which one can apply the verb "to call" meaning "to invoke".

Answer (score 4):

A literal translation of the German "Wie heißt das Buch?" is "How is the book called?" but an idiomatic English translation would be "What is the name of that book?"  I mention this because your other answers have taken the cue from "called" to give you constructions with "called".  When asking what something is "called" it's about a more general property.  "What do you call the man who brings your mail?"  The mailman.  "What is the name of the man who brings your mail?"  Bob.

Comment: In Russian literal translation is very similar to German version, question actually starts with work "Как", that is "How" (or "Wie"). This is a nature of my confusion.

Answer (score -1):

What do you call this?

How do you describe this?

The above two sentences seem OK to me, so I think the correct sentence to go with is:
What is this function called?