# What is the time you spend on a thesis called?

Tags: word-choice, dates

I finished my thesis today and the title page must contain the starting-date and the finishing date of my work on the thesis. What is this time frame called? It should not only include the time I spent with the actual *writing* but also the time I spent preparing the thesis, so all time I spent *working*. All templates I received from university are in German, it's "Bearbeitungszeit" there.

I came up with the following possibilities

- Work time: April 1, 2011 till May 21, 2011
- Work duration: April 1, 2011 till May 21, 2011
- Writing time: April 1, 2011 till May 21, 2011
- Writing duration: April 1, 2011 till May 21, 2011

By the way: Is the date format correct for American English?

Comment: *Nervous breakdown*?  *Living hell*?  (Can you tell I finished my thesis quite recently?)

Comment: By the way, the title should be “What is the time you spend on a thesis called?”, now “How…”; see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26150/how-to-ask-for-a-name-of-some-thing) for explanation/discussion.

Comment: @theomega: Brevity is nearly always a virtue. Why call it anything at all? Just put the range itself on the title page, with a dash between the two dates. In US you could use **04/01/11 - 05/21/11**, but UK and others use the *dd/mm/yy* format. To avoid confusion I'd go for **1 Apr 2011 - 21 May 2011** unless the recipient establishment has its own published standard format.

Comment: @PPL: We could do with a special button on EL&U to auto-generate the text of your post from relevant question titles!

Comment: What country university system is this for? In American universities, I don't think there is a required such field. For countries, you should either have a template, or see another submission to see how they write it in English.

Comment: I used to use 'thesing' a lot. "Can't go out tonight...thesing..."

Comment: I would use *to* rather than *till* in that context.

Comment: from April 1, 2011 to May 21, 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best literal translation I can find of "Bearbeitungszeit" is "processing time", which really sounds odd here.  I think I would use "Thesis period:"

Your dates are correct for American English, but I would use "through" instead of "till", or perhaps an em dash.

So:

Thesis period:  April 1, 2011 through May 21, 2011

or

Thesis period:  April 1, 2011–May 21, 2011

Comment: ...and of course that comes out as an en dash instead of an em.  Ah well.

Comment: I think maybe you might have meant it came out as a hyphen instead of an en dash? I've edited it to be an en dash, which looks better to me - but you can edit to an em dash if that works better for you...

Comment: @psmears - you're right; I should have either said "hyphen" or used the HTML character.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is:

```
       "Thesis writing duration: 1 April 2011 - 21 May 2011"
```

As I found something about the correct date format.

And The following date formats are not acceptable:

> *31/8/2007
>
> *31-8-2007

Answer (score -1):

I would go for `Research timespan` I guess.

Shouldn't you write April the 1st? or 1st of April? 
And of course : use until instead of till. <strike>I'm not sure till is in the dictionnary.</strike>

#### Edit

Got more precision see: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/till
for usages.

Comment: @M'vy: **Till** is in the dictionary, and could (just about) be used in this context. In informal contexts, **'til** is more common, but wouldn't be suitable here. **Untill**, on the other hand, doesn't exist at all. The best approach is simply to use **to**.

Comment: "Untill" is NOT correct - it's "until" (one N.)  "Till" and "'til" (the apostrophe indicates that it's a contraction of "until") are acceptable in conversation or in informal writing, but not official.  And none of them fits this context.

Comment: Well I got confused. I meant `until` of course.

Comment: *Till* is a perfectly good word, and is in [Shakespeare](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/gwic.cgi?Path=shakespeare/tragedies/romeoandjuliet/i_v//&Word=for+i+ne'er+saw+true+beauty+till+this+night.#w), the [King James Bible](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3:19&version=KJV), and [all](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/till#Preposition) [reputable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/till) [dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/till?rskey=Hiv4h3&result=1#m_en_gb0864740).  Other than that, completely agreed with your answer :-)

Comment: @MT_Head : One N? one 'l'.

Comment: The date, in American style, is written April 1, as MT_Head describes.

Comment: @Boob - Gaaaah!