# What would you say vs. How would you say

Tags: word-choice, american-english, expression-choice

I want to ask a question what someone would say in or about a certain situation.

Here's a question. 
"How would you say when you had a great time?"

And I'm expecting the answer, 
"It was fun."

Should I say "How would you say when ~?", "How would you say *it* when~?" or "What would you say when~?"
Which one sounds better?

Comment: related, closely: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) and [How to ask for the name of something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26150/how-to-ask-for-the-name-of-something)

Comment: None of the possible duplicates above answer this OP's question. They contain the word "_call_" and ask about the name for a noun phrase: _How do you call a thing that does this?_ vs. _What do you call a thing that does this?_ The question here asks how to pose a question that elicits an answer that is a sentence. It is not about asking how ask about naming something.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't sound like anything that anybody would ask in everyday life. Is it a question asked by an English teacher in order to elicit a particular answer?

If so, then you have various possibilities, For example:

- How could you say that you had a great time?
- What would you say if you had a great time?
- What is another way of saying that you had a great time?

As an aside, if I had had a *great* time, I would probably not just say: *It was fun*. For me this would not be strong enough. I would say: *I had a lot of fun* or *I had a load of fun*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I’ll ask this kind of questions to English learners to introduce a particular expression,  in this case “It was fun.”

Comment: By the way, “How would you say when ~” still sounds OK? but other three questions you mentioned are more proper in this kind of situation?

Comment: "_How would you say when ..._" does not sound right to me. "_What would you say when ..._" is the best of your three possibilities.

Comment: "How would you congratulate someone" or "How would you thank someone" would work.  "How would you say "Good Luck" in "Spanish" would work...  While an improvement on yours, I am not certain that Shoe's "How could you say that you had a good time" is correct or not.  "How could you tell someone that you had a good time" would work.  "Say" is different from "Tell" or "Explain" .   It would work with"How would you say goodbye?" but a 'goodbye' or a 'hello" is a ~type~ of greeting, not a custom message. (also "thank you" or a "good luck").  Not "How would you say when you parted with someone"

Comment: @Tom22. Teachers have various ways of eliciting desired responses in what are known as "_display questions_", such as the one the OP is asking about. And you can certainly use _tell_ (plus _someone_) instead of _say_. However, I don't think there is anything wrong with "_How could you say that you had a good time_". Using "_could_" instead of "_would_" suggests that there is one than one possible response. But I agree that "_How would you say when you parted with someone_ does not work. Better is, for example, "_What do you say when you part from someone?_".